# Comparing int array element values Java

Tags: java, arrays, int, compare

Trying to compare the elements of an array. For instance, would like to return a boolean if array[0][0] was equal to array[0][1].  I figured seeing if two elements were not equal would be easier. So

```
boolean rowAlike = true;

for(int row = 0; row<size; row++)
        {
           for(int col = 0;col<size;col++)
           {
              nextNum = col + 1;
              if(!square[row][col].equals(square[row][nextNum]))
                 rowAlike=false;
           }
           if(rowAlike)
              System.out.println("All digits are the same in row " +row++);
```

Since arrays are reference variables I know that == will compare the memory locations rather than the values of those elements. I tried it they way above and also tried

```
     Arrays.equals(square[row][col],(square[row][nextNum])
```

I either get a false false or a compiler error.

EDIT: the false false I receive is when using `==` I get a compiler error using `.equals`

> ExploreMatrix.java:89: error: int cannot be dereferenced

And when using Arrays.equals

> ExploreMatrix.java:89: error: no suitable method found for equals(int,int)

Comment: `I either get a false false or a compiler error. ` Well, which is it? And if it is a compiler error why not share it in your question?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally omitted that part of the code. square is the two dimensional array. Size is set by the user. Both dimensions are always the same.

Comment: You can edit your question. And format it.

Comment: So an array is a reference type. But an `int` is a primitive type. What don't you understand about the errors?

Comment: I understand the errors. I want to know how, if there is a way, I can compare the two elements.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this situation is exactly what I was looking for so it gets a +1 from me.

Comment: @BinaryBrian  Did you figure out why you were getting false when using '=='?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitives (such as `int`) are tested by values with `==` and/or `!=` (as appropriate). You need to define the `rowAlike` in the loop body (or it won't reset on the next row). Accessing `col + 1` when `col == size - 1` will result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. I suggest you start at `1` and then compare to the previous. Next, you can `break` in your loop when you first find a value that doesn't match. Finally, for display, you shouldn't modify the value of `row` (or you will skip a row). Putting it all together,

```
int[][] square = new int[size][size];
//
// ... Setup values in square ...
//
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    boolean rowAlike = true;
    for (int col = 1; col < size; col++) {
        if (square[row][col - 1] != square[row][col]) {
            rowAlike = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (rowAlike) {
        System.out.printf("All digits are the same in row %d%n",
                row + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!square[row][col].equals(square[row][nextNum]))
```

The code above will work if your `square` is an array of `String`.

Unfortunately, you did not define `square` in your question.

Use `==` for comparing primitive types like `int` and `.equals` for comparing `String`

Comment: `.equals`will work (compile) for _any_ Object (i.e. non-primitive type), since `equals`-method is defined in `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- Most likely, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs (which is a
  `RuntimeException`) here:

  ```
  for(int col = 0;col<size;col++){
     nextNum = col + 1;
     if(!square[row][col].equals(square[row][nextNum]))
     //...
  }
  ```

  In the last iteration, `col`will be `size-1`, which means `nextNum`will be equal to the arrays size. An array of size `x` has
  indices `0`to `x-1`.
- You increment `row`twice (`for`-loop and `SYSOUT`)
- > I know that == will compare the memory locations

  This does not apply for primitive types. According to your Exception, you try to compare `int`-values. Go for `==`.
- Check the [JavaDoc of `Arrays#equals()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-boolean:A-boolean:A-).